# Split text using Python

Tags: python, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python split string on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995892/python-split-string-on-regex)

How do I split some text using Python's `re` module into **two parts**: the text before a special word `cut` and the rest of the text following it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please improve the quality of your question.

Comment: A great way to improve the quality of your question is to search for all the questions which are **exactly** like this one.  Here's a list: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+re+split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, might help you

```
>>> re.compile('[0-9]+').split("hel2l3o")
['hel', 'l', 'o']
>>> 

>>> re.compile('cut').split("hellocutworldcutpython")
['hello', 'world', 'python']

split about first cut 

>>> l=re.compile('cut').split("hellocutworldcutpython")
>>> print l[0], string.join([l[i] for i in range(1, len(l))], "")
hello worldpython
```

Comment: need ***TWO* part ['hello', 'worldcutpython']

Comment: can you please explain it clearly

Comment: Need text only before txt and after.

Comment: >>> l=re.compile('cut').split("hellocutworldcutpython")
>>> print l[0], string.join([l[i] for i in range(1, len(l))], "")
hello worldpython

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('cut', s, 1) # Split only once.
```

But in this case you can just use `str.split`:

```
>>> s.split('cut', 1) # Split only once.
```