# Getting column widths from string in python

Tags: python, string

I have the foll. string:

```
'    Y   M   D     PDSW      RSPC      NPPC       NEE'
```

Each element in the string corresponds to a column in a csv file. Is there a way (aside from for loops), of getting the width of each column from this string? E.g. Th first column has a width of 5 ('    Y'), the next has a width of 4('   M')...

Comment: .. And what is wrong with doing it the way you suggest: with a loop?

Comment: nothing wrong per se, just hoping if there is a more pythonic way

Comment: Is using a regex also Not The Python Way? (Guess based on http://stackoverflow.com/q/4995892/2564301 - you'd just have to capture sets of *n* spaces followed by *m* not-spaces).

Comment: wouldn't regex eat up the spaces too?

Comment: The accepted answer suggests not. There is also an alternative that uses `findall` in lieu of `split`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
>>> text = '    Y   M   D     PDSW      RSPC      NPPC       NEE'
>>> cols = re.findall('\s+\S+', text)
>>> [len(col) for col in cols]
[5, 4, 4, 9, 10, 10, 10]
```

So - assume the columns (right-aligned) are one or more spaces followed by one or more non-space, then take the lengths of the resulting strings.