# Separating HTML file with keyword for scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am programming in Python with Scrapy and have a huge `html` file with a structure similar to the one demonstrated below:

```
<span>keyword</span>
<title>Title 1</title>
<span>Date 1</span>
<div>Content 1</div>

<span>keyword</span>
<title>Title 2</title>
<span>Date 2</span>
<div>Content 2</div>

...

<span>keyword</span>
<title>Title N</title>
<span>Date N</span>
<div>Content N</div>
```

My goal is to get all the `title`, `date`, and contents inside `div` for each section, but the sections themselves are not located in separated `div` or other elements, just one after another until the N-th section.

While I can try to get all the `title[1:N]`, `date[1:N]`, and `div[1:N]` as a list with `len() = N`, doing so prevent debugging as if `N` goes to 10,000 and `len(title)==len(date)==len(div) -> False`, it will be hard to find where thing goes wrong (e.g. some titles are put in `<strong>` instead of `<title>`).

One item I noticed is to the **keyword** located between each section. With the help of that keyword, is it possible to separate the entire `html` into N parts, and hopefully get `item[i] = ["Title_i", "Date_i", "DIV_i"]` for each section through iteration?

This way missing data will be represented as `item[1]=["", Date_i, Div_i ]` and will be much easier to locate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carl, you may try to split html file content into concise parts by keywords.

1. You should be able to know a full set/dictionary of all possible keywords.
2. Some keywords might be duplicated inside of any `Content` part... so you'd better split not with pure keyword values, nor with `<span>keyword</span>` expression but with the most unique `<span>keyword</span>\s*<title>` and `<span>keyword</span><strong>` expressions. Thus you split parts correctly with a big probability.

Comment: Thanks @igor,  would you do this simple through a `str.split` method?

Comment: @carl_pch, seems to me to split in this case you'd need regex expressions. See [this example of split with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995892/python-split-string-on-regex). Yet you might test it with pure string delimiter. Try both ways in test mode...

Comment: thanks for the updated answer! I was actually using xpath to get all the elements from my data, but as stated, if I just get all the `html.xpath('//title/text()'')`, when 1 or 2 titles are missed, it's hard to find out what went wrong with this approach along, therefore the splitting question -- So the old answer still helps!

Comment: @carl_pch, how about to mix both approaches applying smth. like this:`html.xpath("//title/text()[preceding-sibling::span='keyword' and following-sibling::span='keyword']")`  ?

Comment: that's a great idea! I should def look deeper into `xpath`'s functions, somehow it didn't occur to me that `text()` can also be followed by `preceding-sibling`, I will try it then! thanks again

Comment: @carl_pch, that idea I've got from the [second post](http://scraping.pro/extracting-sequential-html-element/) that I've mentioned in my update answer.